# Efficient way of finding index of element of one array in another array without using pandas

Tags: python, numpy

suppose I have two array
`arr1`  and `arr2`

`arr1 = ["ABC","DEF","GHI","XYZ"]`

`arr2 = ["ABC","XYZ"]`

I need the index of element of `arr2` in `arr1`.

required result =[0,3]

I am able to do this using pandas but need an effective way of doing maybe by numpy.

```
A = pd.series(arr1)
B = pd.series(arr2)

B.map(lambda x: np.where(A==x)[0][0]).tolist()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `np.where` this way:

```
>>> np.where(np.isin(arr1, arr2))[0]
array([0, 3], dtype=int64)
>>>
```

If you want a list:

```
>>> np.where(np.isin(arr1, arr2))[0].tolist()
[0, 3]
>>>
```